# Why wont Firefox Display/Work Correctly with the given CSS?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

i have no problems seeing the page in IE or Chrome and the Upload button works in both.. but in FireFox it doesnt displat the widths correctly nor does the upload button works..

i cant seem to find anythiong wrong with the code... here is the entire page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:verdana;
color:#3f3f3f;
font-size:14px;
}
html,body{
height:100%;
}
#container{
width:1024px;
margin:0 auto;
height:100%;
}
#content{
min-height:100%;
background-color:#fff;
width:804px;
padding:5px;
float:left;
display:inline;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-right:10px;
}
body{
background-color:rgb(228, 228, 228);
}
table{
width:450px;
margin:0 auto;
}
table td{
padding:10px 5px;
}
table th{
background-color:rgb(116, 116, 116);
color:#fff;
padding:10px;
text-align:left;
font-weight:normal;
font-size:16px;
}
table label{
display:block;
padding-bottom:3px;
font-weight:bold;
}
table input[type=text], table select{
display:block;
color:rgb(116, 116, 116);
padding:8px;
line-height:20px;
border:1px solid rgb(183, 187, 202);
font-weight:bold;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
width:260px;
}
table select{
width:277px;
}
#txtEmail, #ctitle, #txtDesc{
width:550px;
}

/* Upload Button */
table input[type=file]{
text-align: right;
/* start of transparency styles */
opacity:0;
-moz-opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity:0);
/* end of transparency styles */
z-index:2;
cursor:pointer;
}
#fileName{
width:196px;
display:inline;
margin:0;
}
.uploadbtn{
display:block;
padding:0;
margin:0;
font-weight:normal;
width:60px;
display:inline-block;
height:38px;
line-height:38px;
vertical-align:middle;
background-color:#3f3f3f;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
float:right;
cursor:pointer;
}
/*********************/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><th colspan="2">Informacion de Contacto</th></tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Nombre</label><input type="text" maxlength="20" id="txtName" name="txtName"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>Apellido</label><input type="text" maxlength="20" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Telefono</label><input type="text" maxlength="13" id="txtTel1" name="txtTel1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>Telefono Adicional</label><input type="text" maxlength="13" id="txtTel2" name="txtTel2"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <label>Email</label><input type="text" maxlength="100" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><th colspan="2">Informacion del Clasificado</th></tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <label>Titulo</label><input type="text" maxlength="100" id="ctitle" name="ctitle"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <label>Descripcion</label><textarea name="cbody" cols="78" rows="10" id="cbody" ></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Precio</label><input type="text" maxlength="9" id="txtPrecio" name="txtPrecio"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>Comentario (OMO,FIJO,etc)</label><input type="text" maxlength="10" id="txtPriceComment" name="txtPriceComment"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Tipo de Clasificado</label>
        <select>
            <option>Venta</option>
            <option>Adopcion</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>Categoria</label>
        <select>
            <option>Perros</option>
            <option>Gatos</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Pueblo</label>
        <select>
            <option>Area Metro</option>
            <option>Bayamon</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>Foto</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="100" id="fileName" name="fileName"/>
        <label class="uploadbtn">Upload
            <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value"/>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `</head>
</body>` -- what?

Comment: just fixed the tag, sorry typo while copying it over

Comment: no Jan, it did not solve the issue

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle of your code... http://jsfiddle.net/R3RCu/

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that each browser renders **input file** element differently and Firefox is rendering your **input file** away from your **label**. So when you click on your **label**, you are not clicking on **input file**. Am I being clear?

Please see this tutorial how to create a custom **input file** cross browser compatible.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Let me know if this helped you

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't forget the mime type on your stylesheet

```
<style></style>
```

to

```
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

Comment: just aded the mime type and it still has the same issue, but thanks for the tip for the mime type

Comment: You haven't had to add that in years to any browser. All browsers default to 'text/css' and it's even written into the spec: http://developers.whatwg.org/semantics.html#the-style-element